# How to switch between Symfony Environments?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, nginx

I got my `Symfony 3.4` application deployed using `PROD` environment following this guide: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/deployment.html (seems that, **by default**, was running on PROD, since I does not selected any environment during installation...)

In the near future, this machine will take the `PRE-PRODUCTION` role, so I created a new environment called `pre` for my application following this guide: http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html#creating-a-new-environment

Now I'm wondering how to switch this machine to new `PRE` environment.
I read these guides, but I'm still confused:

1) http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments

2) http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html

On the current machine, I'm using `Apache`; but for production, and following updates, I'll considere to start using `NGINX`. So, both options are appreciated.

Comment: do you have the web folder or the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the instructions in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html#creating-a-new-environment) you've entered:

> Because you'll want this environment to be accessible via a browser, you should also create a front controller for it. Copy the web/app.php file to web/app_benchmark.php and edit the environment to be benchmark

then you have `app_pre.php` front controller with this line:

`$kernel = new AppKernel('pre', false);`

Just point your Apache web server to use `app_pre.php` instead of `app.php` as the front controller and your environment is *switched*.